# Race a local user ghost in Mario Kart 8 Deluxe

Tags: mario-kart-8-deluxe

Is there a way to race other local user's ghosts in Mario Kart 8 on the Switch?

We use three different user accounts, only one has a Nintendo account and none has an online subscription.

Is there any way to be able to race Time Trial ghosts from other local users without an Online presence?